# Is it ok to move from a dim5 to a p5 when moving from vii6 to I6?

Tags: harmony, voice-leading

Usually moving from a dim5 to a p5 is not a good idea but in this progression is it ok? You can see the dim5 doesn't resolve in the I6 chord but the voice exchange makes it quite smooth. Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: I thought the 5th of a vii°6 chord typically resolves down (from Eb to D in your case), rather like the 7th of a V7 chord, resulting in doubling the 3rd of the I6 chord.

Comment: not sure doubling the bass of a I6 is a good idea

Comment: @Dekkadeci, I think the parallel chords of the sixth mitigate that non-resolving FA. Of course the "way out" of the problem is to make `viio6` a `V6/4`.

Comment: I havent gotten to 6/4 chords yet but my textbook says that the vii6 is a very useful chord for scale degree 2 in the bass.

Comment: What do you mean by vii6. I can't think of anything other than what would be tantamount to V7 in first inversion. Is the triad diminished or minor?

Comment: @Rosie I meant the vii diminished chord in 1st inversion

Comment: Michael I tried it with  passing 6/4 instead of the diminished chord and it is much smoother... not that the other one is bad sounding but the 6/4 V in there is really nice.

Comment: @armani Yes, << { e'f'g' } \\ { c'b c' } \\ { g g g } \\ { c d e } >> is a cliché I was taught in 4-part harmony lessons. Going from a dim 5th to a P 5th or vice versa is *not* considered to be consecutive 5ths.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is absolutely okay and appears countless times in the repertoire.

This particular voice-exchange progression is *very* common, and the way you've written it is the smoothest voice leading. That diminished fifth moving to perfect fifth is absolutely fine.

Another option is to move the tenor down to F, but it's not necessary.

Some stricter traditions say that motion from diminished fifth to perfect fifth is wrong. A less strict option is that this is only wrong when it involves the soprano. Personally, I see diminished fifths moving to perfect fifths so often in the repertoire that I see no reason to treat it as an error.

Comment: Lennie's Maria's a good example, no?

Comment: @Tim I'm at the gym and can't hear it. Got a timestamp?

Comment: is this a rare case that it is acceptable that a dim5 moves to a P5 or are there lots of other cases?

Comment: @armani In my opinion, there are plenty of other cases. But others disagree :-)

Comment: Richard.. its like that huh? Well what about this? https://ibb.co/kyYYS1m . My textbook says that when moving to a 5/3 chord the dim 5 interval in the vii6 dim chord should resolve. But this contrary motion between the soprano and bass is nice!

Comment: @armani I agree, that contrary motion is nice. The fact is, these things are completely up to individual circumstances. In the particular case you just shared, I admit that sounds less "okay" to me because a) the interval involves the soprano, and b) it also involves the alto, so that motion is at the top of the texture, completely separated from the bottom two voices. But that's just me!

Comment: ok thank you! so then is it not possible to have this soprano melody with this chord progression? according to your ear anyway...

Comment: @armani It really depends on who you ask and who is teaching. Some would say definitely not. Some would say it's totally fine. Others (like me) would say "it's not completely wrong, but we can make it better." Sorry, I know that's a non-answer!